# Prevent automatic deployment on manual release definition creation

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We currently have a setup where we schedule a pipeline to create a new release definition at 4am every Sunday. 
We have setup one of our test stages to trigger deployment 'After Release'.

This works perfectly and deploys the new release automatically, however the issue we have is that because we have set the 'After Release' trigger on our test stage, every time someone creates a release definition *manually* then the stage deployed as well.

We only want the stage to deploy if the release definition was created automatically **not** manually.

Our issue seems to stem from having to set the 'After Release' trigger on the stage.

Is there a way to configure this not to deploy on manual creation? or another approach we could take?

Comment: Just to clarify if I get this right. You have a release pipeline with stage(s) like building and then you have test stage(s). And you want the build stage(s) to always run after release creation but the test stage(s) not when some person clicked the button manually. Is that correct?

Comment: If yes, then there is a way of doing that but it's messy. As of now there is no out of the box solution. If that's what you need let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the version you are using, there should be an option when creating the release to change the stage trigger from automatic to manual.  You could just provide training for those with release creation rights to make sure they specify that setting.

[image]